# Individual legends for separate geom_line aesthetics in the same ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I'm new to R and I'm trying to create a single plot with data from 2 melted dataframes.
Ideally I would have a legend for each of the dataframes with their respective titles; however, I get a only a single legend with the title of the first aesthetic.
My starting point is:

```
aerobic_melt <- melt(aerobic, id.vars = 'Distance', variable.name = 'Aerobic')
anaerobic_melt <- melt(anaerobic, id.vars = 'Distance', variable.name = 'Anaerobic')
plot <- ggplot() +
  geom_line(data = aerobic_melt, aes(Distance, value, col=Aerobic)) +
  geom_line(data = anaerobic_melt, aes(Distance, value, col= Anaerobic)) +
  xlim(0, 125) +
  ylab('Energy (J/kg )') +
  xlab('Distance (m)')
```

Which results in

[image: As far as I got]

I've searched, but with my limited ability I haven't been able to find a way to do it.

My question is:
How do I create separate legends with titles 'Aerobic' and 'Anaerobic' which should respectively refer to A,B,C,F,G,L and E,H,I,J,K?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously we don't have your data, but I have created some sample data that should have the same names and structure as your own data frames, since it works with your own plot code. See the end of the answer for the data used here.

You can use the package `ggnewscale` if you want two color scales on the same plot. Just add in a `new_scale_color()` call between your `geom_line` calls. I have left the rest of your code as-is.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggnewscale)

plot <- ggplot() +
  geom_line(data = aerobic_melt, aes(Distance, value, col=Aerobic)) +
  new_scale_color() +
  geom_line(data = anaerobic_melt, aes(Distance, value, col= Anaerobic)) +
  xlim(0, 125) +
  ylab('Energy (J/kg )') +
  xlab('Distance (m)')

plot
```

[image]

---

**Data**

```r
set.seed(1)

aerobic_melt <- data.frame(
  Aerobic = rep(c("A", "B", "C", "F", "G", "L"), each = 120),
  value   = as.numeric(replicate(6, cumsum(rnorm(120)))),
  Distance = rep(1:120, 6))

anaerobic_melt <- data.frame(
  Anaerobic = rep(c("E", "H", "I", "J", "K"), each = 120),
  value   = as.numeric(replicate(5, cumsum(rnorm(120)))),
  Distance = rep(1:120, 5))
```

Comment: Thanks Allan! This gave me exactly what I needed!